# how to hook up the moment when a Thread has been destroyed

Tags: java, multithreading

Is there any place to hook up when a Thread has been killed? Something like :

```
onDestroy{
 //do something...
}
```

EDIT:
Sorry. I should have stated it more clearly.

The thread termination is not because all the job has done but because it has been killed by the client code using `ThreadGroup.destroy()`. As my singleton is being instantiated in the client code, so it will belong to the THreadGroup of the Client code and  be killed as a result. (Actually, I am not very sure of the last sentence...)

Comment: I wonder if there is something via [JMX](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/javamanagement-140525.html)?

Comment: what? http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadGroup.html See method "destroy()". It clearly says "the thread group must be empty, indicating that all threads have since been stopped" ===> this means that it will kill no thread

Comment: Maybe you'd better to describe us what are you trying to achieve. What do you want it to happen to your singleton? Why do you want to terminate the thread?

Comment: @ignis, I am trying to find a way that either prevent my Thread being terminated or set flag so that i create another thread later on.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can wrap both the action and the hook like this.

```
public final class HookOnDestroy implements Runnable {
    private final Runnable action;
    private final Runnable hook;
    public HookOnDestroy(Runnable action, Runnable hook) {
          this.hook = hook;
          this.action = action;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
       try {
         action.run();
       } finally {
         hook.run();
       }
    }

}
```

and

```
Runnable action = ...
Runnable hook = ...
new Thread( new HookOnDestroy(action,hook)).start();
```

Answer (score 5):

There's no general way to add an asynchronous listener to a thread that gets notified when the thread dies. You can use the `join` method to wait for a thread, but that is synchronous. Or you could create an extension of thread class that calls listeners at the end of its run method, something like:

```
public abstract class NotifyingThread extends Thread {
     private final List<ThreadListeners> listeners;

     protected abstract void doRun();

     public void run() {
         doRun();
         notifyListeners();
     }

}
```

Comment: Jeff, my thread is running in a while loop and it will be destroyed by some one mistakenly. I want to know this and start another thread once it has been destroyed.

Comment: @jeff, what about "try { run(); } finally { notifyListeners(); }"?

Comment: @pierr, what do you mean it will be destroyed by someone mistakenly?

Comment: @jeff, a lazy copy from my email to explain:  "So far we canceling all threads that are created in the Xlet Thread Group. It seems to be your case, because your singleton is being instantiated in the class loader/thread group of the Xlet."

Comment: @pierr, I don't understand what that means

Comment: @jeff, sorry. Please see my rephrase in the EDIT of the post.

Comment: It's not like someone else is walking around in your code and terminating threads on you. It sounds like they are executing *features* in your application which result in the threads being killed. It's your job as the developer to build the program so that it calls the code you want when this "mistaken" feature is triggered, and/or prevent the mistaken termination in the first place.

Comment: Checkout @John's answer. His solution does provide a mechanism.

Answer (score 3):

Killed or interrupted?

If you are watching for an attempt to interrupt your thread, the easiest way to do so is to catch an InterruptedException.  In super pseudo code:

```
// in my Thread
public void run() {
    try {
        boolean keepRunning = true;
        while (keepRunning) {
            // Do useful work
            // Call other methods
            // As long as they aren't also catching InterruptedException
        }
        System.err.println("Finished running since keepRunning is now false");
    } catch (InterrruptedException ie) {
        // This is where you would put your "onDestroy" functionality
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

@Jeff is correct.

> ... and it will be destroyed by some one mistakenly.

Threads don't get "killed" or "destroyed".  They terminate as a result of actions that *they take themselves*.  The two scenarios for a thread terminating are:

- The `run()` method returns.  This typically happens by design; i.e. because the method has finished whatever it was that it was designed to do.
- The `run()` method throws or propagates an exception.  This typically happens as a result of some bug in the thread throwing an unexpected unchecked exception.

(I'm ignoring the possibility that some JVM might implement the deprecated `Thread.destroy()` method, and someone might be crazy enough to call it.)

This is not to say that monitoring thread termination isn't a useful thing to do.  Just that the cause of thread termination is different to what you are hypothesizing in your question / comments.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could start a thread in a different thread group. So, your code would not be running in the Xlet thread group, therefore they would not be able to terminate the thread.